# MySQL select statement remove whitespace in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to match phone numbers based on the last 6 digits. The problem is the numbers in the database are in various formats, some have whitespace within the number.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE trim(phone) LIKE '%123456'
```

Trim only removes the leading and trailing whitespace and doesn't find entries where clients have entered their numbers with whitespace between the numbers:
123 456, 12 34 56, etc.

So how to remove the whitespace within the search? Having the result without whitespace is not enough. Updating the database with replace is not an option either.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace()` to substitute all occurrences of ' ' to '' within a string.

[mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)
```

Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str replaced by the string to_str. REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive match when searching for from_str.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Replace(coalesce(Phone,''), ' ','') LIKE '%123456'
```

If you can't do it in the where clause, which seems odd to me; just nest it in a select.

```
Select sub.* 
from (Select u.*, Replace(coalesce(Phone,''), ' ','') as ph
               from users u) sub
where sub.ph LIKE '%123456'
```

Comment: Actually I did try this but I get an error on PhpMyAdmin: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near". With trim() function I get no error, but for some reason replace() doesn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing some phone numbers are NULL so we need to coalesce those to empty set ''.

Comment: Still doesn't work with coalesce. Replace only works after SELECT (in the result the number is formatted right) but not after WHERE (so it would find all the entries)

Comment: If you can't use it in the where clause (which seems really odd to me create the value in a subselect then filter by it.